# Terraform | depends_on causes sequence problems for incremental updates

Tags: terraform

Summary: `depends_on` of Terraform works fine, BUT when I have an incremental update with new resources going in-between then it causes the new resources to run in parallel (which will NOT if I run it from scratch)

Example Terraform (Run 1) **Works fine**

```
resource "null_resource" "one" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "NAME='one'; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1;"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "two" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.one]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "NAME='one'; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1;"
  }
}
```

Example Terraform (Run 2)

**Problem**: `before_one` and `after_two` are getting started in parallel :(

**Expected Flow**: complete `before_one` and then start `after_two`

```
resource "null_resource" "before_one" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "NAME='before_one'; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1;"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "one" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.before_one]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "NAME='one'; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1;"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "two" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.one]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "NAME='one'; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1;"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "after_two" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.two]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "NAME='after_two'; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1;"
  }
}
```

Output

```
null_resource.before_one: Creating...
null_resource.before_one: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.after_two: Creating...
null_resource.after_two: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
null_resource.after_two (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "NAME='after_two'; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1;"]
null_resource.after_two (local-exec): after_two
null_resource.before_one (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "NAME='before_one'; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1; echo $NAME; sleep 1;"]
null_resource.before_one (local-exec): before_one
null_resource.after_two (local-exec): after_two
null_resource.before_one (local-exec): before_one
null_resource.after_two (local-exec): after_two
null_resource.before_one (local-exec): before_one
null_resource.after_two: Creation complete after 3s [id=3913800421589569159]
null_resource.before_one: Creation complete after 3s [id=9135396498225807226]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to put the command in the second `null_resource` in the first one so that it runs afterwards?

Comment: Cannot merge sections .In my original use-case each section is a different Helm Release https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release

Comment: Sorry, just released stackexchange has a DevOps section. I have moved the post to https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12587/terraform-depends-on-causes-sequence-problems-for-incremental-updates